# <Accelerate/Accelerate.h> "file not found"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, frameworks

I want to include linear regression to my iPhone app. After some search, I figured out the LAPACK and BLAS in Accelerate Framework is the right libraries to use. But I have a hard time adding accelerate framework to my XCode. I am using XCode 4.3.2 and MAC OS X 10.7.4
When I add the following line to my XCode: #include  it gives me "file not found".

If I remove this line, I can not use any functions from LAPACK or BLAS.
I have copied and paste the framework from:
/system/library/frameworks/Accelerate.framework
to my project folder. I also have added it by control-click on my project in XCode and add the framework. None of these seem to work and I still get the error: `"file not found"`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure you are including the iOS Accelerate Framework in the build settings?

I am unsure how things were in Xcode 4.3.2 but currently you would need to add the framework in the 'Targets' section when you click on the project. Go to build phases and click on — 'Link Binary With Libraries'.

And then simply include using —

```
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
```

Comment: Nice! This header also includes `vDSP`, `vImage` (they are not visible themselves).